# referencing a MongoDB collection using @DBRef annotation inside a list of custom object(DTO) but refence value coming as null

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, dbref

I have a model class

> AssessmentTemplate

which is like this.

```
public class AssessmentTemplate {

@Field("_id")
@Id
private String assessmentId;
private Date creationDate;
private String type;
private String status;
@Field("coreQuestions")
private QuestionTemplate[] coreQuestions;
@Field("baseQuestions")
private QuestionsTemplate[] baseQuestions;
}
```

This is having a nested array of object of

> QuestionsTemplate
> which is like this

```
public class QuestionsTemplate {
@DBRef
private Question questionsId;
private int score;
}
```

> question

```
public class Question {
@Id
private String id;
private String name;
@DBRef
private List<Option> options;
```

}

On querying question, option reference data is getting loaded fine

***On Mongo Side***-I have a collection of *question* and *assessment template*.

While querying data for assessment I am not getting data of question in JSON

need inputs where I might be going wrong.
Do request if any more information is needed.

*Disclaimer*-data added in mongo is through manual JSON input and not through REST endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was not at the java end but on the mongo-end.
the place where I was referencing to question collection I was passing id as

```
"question":{
"$ref":"question",
"$id":"640b87a5dd7cbc1dac84d65a"
}
```

instead of that what worked for me is

```
"question": {
"$ref": "question",
"$id": {
"$oid": "640b87a5dd7cbc1dac84d65a"
}
}
```